# Why React Lazy Load Import Retry doesnt work in IE?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, internet-explorer-11, es6-promise, react-lazy-load

I have situation I want to trigger the retry to assets like chunk.js after deployment, if failed, so that user doesnt see a blank screen. For which this what I did:

```
export const retry = (fn, retriesLeft = 5, interval = 1000) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  fn()
    .then(resolve)
    .catch((error) => {
      if (retriesLeft === 0) {
        // reject('maximum retries exceeded');
        reject(error);
        return;
      }
      setTimeout(() => {
        // Passing on "reject" is the important part
        retry(fn, retriesLeft - 1, interval).then(resolve, reject);
      }, interval);
    });
});

const SomeComponent = React.lazy(() => retry(() => import('someComponent')));
```

Now, this works perfectly fine with Chrome when any of the chunk.js fails to load, as it hits 5 times.(Block any chunk.js call from Dev Tool to observe the behaviour in local)

But with IE 11 the retry doesnt occur at all. Please enlighten why does it behave so.

[Reference](https://dev.to/goenning/how-to-retry-when-react-lazy-fails-mb5)

Comment: Maybe a polyfill would do the trick?

Comment: @Shawn Yap How can I add it?

Comment: @Rajesh This is a React App in Create-React-App which has all the setup of Babel and Webpack... i believe it transpile everything into required JS and also this is a new feature i have added in already working application which has implementation of ARROW Methods everywhere and its working

Comment: Is there any error in console in IE? Could you please provide a minimal sample which can reproduce the issue? You could use some online code editors like stackblitz. Besides, `Promise` is [not supported by IE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#Browser_compatibility). You need to add [polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-polyfill) for it to work in IE.

Comment: Here's the docs to add polyfill https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-app-polyfill

Comment: Adding pllyfill didnt help, can someone try this out ?

Comment: Which polyfill do you add? Please provide a sample to reproduce.